# Transfer of control from JFrame back to the calling class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

I am making a project in which I have a class named `runner_HMMPayl` from the main of this class I am initiating a `JFrame0 f` instance. `JFrame0` returns the values of text fields in `JFrame0` that are then used in main.

I am facing a problem that when I instantiate the `JFrame0`, it keeps on running and control is not shifted back to main of `runner_HMMPayl` class. How can I do that?

These are the relevant code snippets.

First one is the main, making `JFrame0` instance.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    JFrame0 f = new JFrame0();
    f.Start(f);
    System.out.println("f closed"); //not displayed in console----------
    System.out.println("First argument" + args[0]); //not displayed in console-
}
```

This is the code of the `JFrame0` button, which upon pressing should return the arguments.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    argA[0]= "1";

    String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
    argA[1] = s1;
    String s2 = jTextField7.getText();
    argA[2] = s2;
    // ..
    String s7 = jTextField2.getText();
    argA[7] = s7;

    runner.configureHMMPayl(argA); //function in runner_HMMpayl class (instance:runner)
    runner.giveArgs(argA); //function in runner_HMMpayl class 
 }
```

I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

Use a modal `JDialog` to stop execution until the dialog is closed.

See [How to make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

And while you're at it, check out [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)